# How to work with StoryBoard referencing in UITableview or UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, storyboard-reference

I have a table view and clicking on each cell open up a different flow of view controllers.

I know that Xcode 7 has storyboard reference where we can link the flow in two different storyboards, but I don't know whether it's possible for UITableview Cell or UICollectionview item.

I have tried dragging a storyboard reference and tried to connect to a View controller and its not allowing me to do it but If I try to connect the View controller to a Storyboard reference, it works.

**I want to know how storyboard referencing will work for UITableview Cell or UICollectionview item where each cell/item has different flow, and is it possible to invoke a storyboard reference programatically?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference to a view controller that is on another storyboard. You can use the following code:

```
var yourStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Your Storyboard Name", bundle: nil)
var yourVC         = yourStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Your VC Id") as! YourVCType
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to use a **storyboard reference** in **interface builder** while **dynamically updating the flow** depending on (UITableView/UICollectionView) cell tapped.

1. **Manual Segue** - UITableViewController/UICollectionViewController to Storyboard Reference and trigger the segue by code using [`performSegueWithIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:). This would be needed if each cell prototype has different actual segues which it could take.
2. **Selection Segue** - Selection Segue from cell (UITableView/UICollectionView) then use [`prepareForSegue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:) to prepare the destination view controller accordingly. If you are using the same segue/view controller this would be a simpler way to go.